# Missing a curly brace in my PHP clode

Tags: php

I am missing a curly brace that I cannot find.  The **parse error** is showing at the end of my code.  I have spent forever on this. I am not very good with PHP hints in how to ID these errors would be helpful.

```
<?php 

                /*Required Fields*/
                require_once('websiteconfig.inc.php');
                include (ABSOLUTE_PATH . 'class/person.class.php');

                /*Starts the session for the person class*/
                session_start();


                /*FUNCTIONS*/

                /*VERRIFY EMAIL ADDRESS AND PASSWORD AND MATCH IN SYSTEM*/
                function validateLogin($emailaddress='', $password=''){

                /*INITIALIZES VARIABLES*/
                $email_key = 'betty@abc.com';
                $password_key = '1234';

                $auth_match = 0;

                /* CHECK FOR MATCH */
                if($emailaddress == $email_key && $password == $password_key){
                    $auth_match = 1;
                    }
                return $auth_match;
                }

                /*CLEAN FORM DATA*/
                function sanitize($form_var) {
                    $clean_data = strtolower(trim($form_var));

                    return $clean_data;
                }

                /*PAGE VARIABLES*/
                $auth_status = 0;

                /*DETERMINE FORM HAS BEEN SUBMITTED*/
                if(array_key_exists('submit', $_POST)) {

                /*SANITIZE FORM DATA*/
                $emailaddress = sanitize($_POST['emailaddress']);
                $password = sanitize($_POST['password']);

                /*VALIDATE FORM DATA*/
                $auth_status = validateLogin($emailaddress, $password); 

                }


                /*CONFIRM EACH FIELD WAS PROCESSED*/
                //trigger login field exception
                try{
                    if($emailaddress == '' || $password == ''){
                        throw new Exception('E-mail and password must be supplied to login.  Please try again.');
                    }else{
                        /*VALIDATE FOR DATA*/
                        $auth_status = validateLogin($emailaddress, $password);

                        //trigger validation exception


                        try{
                            if(!isset($auth_status)) {
                                throw new Exception('Online Banking is not available at this time.  Please try again later.');
                            }
                        }



                        // catch validation exception
                        catch(Exception $v) {
                            echo 'message: ' . $v->getMessage();
                            exit();
                        } //end catch

                        //This triggers the validation of authentication
                        try{
                            if ($auth_status == 0){
                            throw new Exception('Email address and or Password does not meet our records!  Please try again.');
                            }elseif ($auth_status>0){
                                /*Member Session*/
                                $currentMember = new Person($auth_status);

                                /*Set Attributes*/
                                $currentMember->memberid = $auth_status;
                                $currentMember->firstname = 'Michael';
                                $currentMember->lastname = 'Crawley';
                                $currentMember->emailaddress = 'MichaelCrawley@sort.com';

                                /*Serialize currentMember object*/
                                $_SESSION['currentMember'] = serialize($currentMember);

                    }
                }// End try statment

                //catch login field exception
                catch(Exception $e) {
                    echo 'Message: ' . $e->getMessage();
                    exit();
                        }                   

            ?>





        </div><div class="container" id="shadow">
        <div>
            <?php 

                include(ABSOLUTE_PATH . 'header.inc.php');

                if($auth_status == 1){
                    /*AUTHENTICATION SUCCESS*/
                    echo '<h4>Welcome Back, Betty!</4>' . "\n\n";
                    echo '<ul>' . "\n";
                    echo "\t"  . '<li><a href="' . APP_ROOT . 'onlinebanking" title="Online Banking">Online Banking</a></li>' . "\n\n";
                    echo '</ul>';


                } elseif($auth_status == 0){
                    /*AUTHENTICATION FAILED*/
                    echo '<h4 class="error">Authentication Error!</h4>' . "\n\n";
                    echo '<p>Incorrect e-mail address and/or password submitted. Please try again.</p>';
                }

            ?>




                </div><!--End of main content-->
            <?php 
                include(ABSOLUTE_PATH . 'footer.inc.php');
            ?>

</div>
```

Comment: If you use an editor like Notepad++, it will automatically match up and color code your braces for you. That's how I do it...

Comment: you shuold really pay attention to indenting your code properly. see a few standards here, choose one and follow it properly. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style

Comment: Your last else if. You wrote elseif

Comment: @JérômeMahuet In PHP, elseif is correct. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Answer (score 2):

A common way to ensure proper bracket matching is to to indent the contents of each {} by one more tab than the outside.

Answer (score 0):

You miss a 'catch' to 'try' construction opened at line 54 in your sorce code.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your code

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

But when you cannot find the error, start deleting sections of code and run the file web page again until the error disappears.

eg remove the include footer.inc.php from your code, remove some of the PHP code to actually find what is causing the error. Then you can slowly add code back in to see what triggers your error.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this is not what SO would be for, but...

```
if($emailaddress == '' || $password == ''){
  throw new Exception('E-mail and password must be supplied to login.  Please try again.');
}else{
  /*VALIDATE FOR DATA*/
```

The "else" here doesn't seem to have a matching closing brace. At least, according to my text-editor which has brace-matching in it. (Worth looking into...)

UPDATE: You appear to be missing 2 x closing braces, actually. See reformatted code below:
(See `### THIS BRACE IS UNMATCHED ###` markers.)

```
<?php 
/*Required Fields*/
require_once( 'websiteconfig.inc.php' );
include( ABSOLUTE_PATH . 'class/person.class.php' );

/*Starts the session for the person class*/
session_start();

/*FUNCTIONS*/

/*VERRIFY EMAIL ADDRESS AND PASSWORD AND MATCH IN SYSTEM*/
function validateLogin($emailaddress='', $password=''){

  /*INITIALIZES VARIABLES*/
  $email_key = 'betty@abc.com';
  $password_key = '1234';

  $auth_match = 0;

  /* CHECK FOR MATCH */
  if($emailaddress == $email_key && $password == $password_key){
    $auth_match = 1;
  }
  return $auth_match;
}

/*CLEAN FORM DATA*/
function sanitize($form_var) {
  $clean_data = strtolower(trim($form_var));

  return $clean_data;
}

/*PAGE VARIABLES*/
$auth_status = 0;

/*DETERMINE FORM HAS BEEN SUBMITTED*/
if(array_key_exists('submit', $_POST)) {

  /*SANITIZE FORM DATA*/
  $emailaddress = sanitize($_POST['emailaddress']);
  $password = sanitize($_POST['password']);

  /*VALIDATE FORM DATA*/
  $auth_status = validateLogin($emailaddress, $password); 

}


/*CONFIRM EACH FIELD WAS PROCESSED*/
//trigger login field exception
try{ ### THIS BRACE IS UNMATCHED ###
  if($emailaddress == '' || $password == ''){
    throw new Exception('E-mail and password must be supplied to login.  Please try again.');
  }else{ ### THIS BRACE IS UNMATCHED ###
    /*VALIDATE FOR DATA*/
    $auth_status = validateLogin($emailaddress, $password);

    //trigger validation exception


    try{
      if(!isset($auth_status)) {
        throw new Exception('Online Banking is not available at this time.  Please try again later.');
      }
    } // closing `try`



    // catch validation exception
    catch(Exception $v) {
      echo 'message: ' . $v->getMessage();
      exit();
    } //end catch

    //This triggers the validation of authentication
    try{
      if ($auth_status == 0){
        throw new Exception('Email address and or Password does not meet our records!  Please try again.');
      }elseif ($auth_status>0){
        /*Member Session*/
        $currentMember = new Person($auth_status);

        /*Set Attributes*/
        $currentMember->memberid = $auth_status;
        $currentMember->firstname = 'Michael';
        $currentMember->lastname = 'Crawley';
        $currentMember->emailaddress = 'MichaelCrawley@sort.com';

        /*Serialize currentMember object*/
        $_SESSION['currentMember'] = serialize($currentMember);

      }
    }// End try statment

    //catch login field exception
    catch(Exception $e) {
      echo 'Message: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit();
    }                   

?>





</div><div class="container" id="shadow">
<div>
<?php 

    include(ABSOLUTE_PATH . 'header.inc.php');

    if($auth_status == 1){
      /*AUTHENTICATION SUCCESS*/
      echo '<h4>Welcome Back, Betty!</4>' . "\n\n";
      echo '<ul>' . "\n";
      echo "\t"  . '<li><a href="' . APP_ROOT . 'onlinebanking" title="Online Banking">Online Banking</a></li>' . "\n\n";
      echo '</ul>';


    } elseif($auth_status == 0){
      /*AUTHENTICATION FAILED*/
      echo '<h4 class="error">Authentication Error!</h4>' . "\n\n";
      echo '<p>Incorrect e-mail address and/or password submitted. Please try again.</p>';
    }

?>




</div><!--End of main content-->
<?php 
    include(ABSOLUTE_PATH . 'footer.inc.php');
?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most editors will be able to highlight matching pairs of braces.

A tip on how to avoid these: Code conventions! I wont say where exactly to intend what and if the { and } should be on a new line or on the same, but always do it the same way. Over the years you will spot those things pretty fast - if intended correctly